# Where are the relationship rules established in core data in xcode 4?

Tags: core-data, xcode4

This question was [asked earlier in March](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183328/delete-rules-for-relationships-in-core-data-in-xcode-4-beta) before the release of xCode 4, but it's still relevant and no longer protected by NDA. Where are the relationship rules established in core data in xcode 4 assigned? They've disappeared from the utility window. Many thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In graphical mode, you can ctl-drag between entities to establish a new relationship, then select the relationship itself in the graphical entity to reveal/edit relationship information in the Utility view. Alternatively, you can switch "Editor Style" (bottom-right of editor) to Table mode and edit relationships that way.

I'll say it: Xcode 4.0 seems about half-baked. A lot of us were surprised when Apple released it.

Comment: Hi Joshua:Thanks for the prompt answer. How do I set a relationship to cascade on delete?

Comment: The deletion rules are right there with the rest of the relationship editing UI.

Comment: +1 Thanks Joshua. I agree, many issues with Core Data in this early release. Hope they fix these issues.

Comment: Just not too soon. I already re-wrote much of the first half of my Xcode 4 book... ;-)

Comment: There is a bug in which they sometimes won't show up when you select a relationship.  If this happens, restart xcode and complain to Apple.

Comment: To see the utility view, you'll want to select View -> Utilities -> Data Monitor Inspector

Comment: ... or just open the utility view with the button near the right side of the toolbar, then click the Data Model Inspector panel. Either way.

Answer (score 17):

In the main window of Xcode 4, in the upper right corner, select the right-most 'Utilities' view.  You'll find what you need in the Plural: To-Many Relationship.